# Creating a vector in R with if and for - Returning "NA"?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement, vector

I'm a newbie to R so apologies in advance

I am working with R's mtcars dataset and am trying to fill an empty vector using the following code:

```
emptyvec = c()

for (io in mtcars$disp) {
  if(io > 200) {
    emptyvec[io] = io
  }
}
```

While I do get back all values over 200 from the mtcars$disp vector, I also get a lot of NA values too. Is there any reason for that? I have tried multiple ways to fix it but so far, but nothing seems to work. I feel like I am missing something obvious but cannot see it.

I have shown the output from the console below.

P.S. - I've been told there is a way to do this using the for/while loops rather than if. Is that possible? This is a question from an assignment at college. I know there are easier ways, but I'd love to know what I am doing wrong with this specifically so I can improve.

Thanks!

```
 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 225.0
NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 258.0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 275.8
NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
301.0    NA    NA 304.0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 318.0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 350.0
351.0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 360.0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 400.0
NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 440.0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 460.0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA 472.0

Comment: As a general rule, you almost **never** want to create/fill a vector in a loop like this in R. It makes a simple job much more complicated. It’s also, additionally, really inefficient because it requires constantly copying the partially constructed vector. In your case, the canonical solution would be `emptyvec = mtcars$disp[mtcars$disp > 200]`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at `mtcars$disp`:

```
mtcars$disp
 [1] 160.0 160.0 108.0 258.0 360.0 225.0 360.0 146.7 140.8 167.6 167.6 275.8 275.8 275.8 472.0 460.0 440.0  78.7
[19]  75.7  71.1 120.1 318.0 304.0 350.0 400.0  79.0 120.3  95.1 351.0 145.0 301.0 121.0
```

When you use `for (io in mtcars$disp)`, these `disp` values are the values `io` is taking. You have `if(io > 200)`, so nothing happens in your loop until we get to the first value > 200, which is 258.0. And then you run `emptyvec[io] = io`, which is equivalent to `emptyvec[258] = 258`. At this point, you've told `emptyvec` to fill it 258th element, so everything up to that point defaults to `NA`.

You probably mean to do this:

```
emptyvec = c()

## loop over the indices of the vector: 1, 2, 3, ...
## not over the values: 160, 160, 108, ...
for (io in 1:length(mtcars$disp)) { 
  if(mtcars$disp[io] > 200) { ## reference the ioth value
    emptyvec[io] = mtcars$disp[io]
  }
}
```

But a better way would use vectorization and subsets:

```
result = mtcars$disp
result[result <= 200] = NA
```

Comment: A good place to start but would have been better if the possibility of an NA value for mtcars$disp[io] had been considered and if `seq_along(mtcars$disp)` were used instead of `1:length(mtcars$disp)`. At the moment you will get an error if any of the disp column has NA and the error will look like: `Error in if (NA) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`